# Jquery, using each but restricting it to a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm sure this is trivial but I just can't find the right search terms for it.

Say I have quite a few .field-item divs on a page and I want to use each() only on the instances of .field-item which are within the container div.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='items'>
        <div class="field-item"></div>
        <div class="field-item"></div>
        <div class="field-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I restrict the scope of each()?

Thanks,

Comment: http://api.jquery.com has all the documentation.

Comment: @MattBall This is really not a jQuery question but a CSS question. It is not in the scope of the jQuery API. OP only thought it was a jQuery issue because he was unaware of how this works

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I disagree. jQuery uses a superset of CSS selector syntax but the documentation is still there: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Comment: @MattBall Ah, I had no idea the jQuery API covered css selectors, learn something new every day :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I really did mean it when I said it: http://api.jquery.com/ has ***all*** the documentation.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: jQuery uses a superset of CSS selector syntax that deviates heavily from the standard - for that we have a [jquery-selectors] tag that should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bAUXE/)

```
$('.container .field-item').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```